# Uploading files in NodeJS and notification

Tags: node.js, file-upload, email-notifications

I'm building a node application where users should be able to upload multiple files and once all the files are uploaded an email should be sent to root user, the email should also contain the link to the uploaded files so that root user can access those files which were uploaded by user. How should I approach this problem. Should I keep those uploaded files to the application server or I should use some static storage service like Amazon S3. These files are image files.

Answer (score 2):

While using S3 has many advantage like,scalability extendability and security, it also has pricing side of it. So it depends on the file how sensitive and important it is. Amazon provides robust api to handle any type of file. It also support pause and resume upload, multipart upload, and version control. So if the files are important and performance matters go for S3, you can leverage built in API's for it.

The biggest disadvantage of using application server is scalability. Since we are talking image files the size would depend on the quality and scaling up the server can be a tedious task, building the api which is capable enough to manage is not easy if not impossible.